# Is gdef wrapped in newcommand syntactic sugar or are there other benefits?

Tags: macros

In a package class, I read:

```
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
    \gdef\@subtitle{#1}
}
```

I wonder whether this is syntactic sugar for setting the subtitle easily with `\subtitle{value}` and whether this is equivalent to `\gdef\subtitle{value}`? without the above helper command?

Comment: No, it's equivalent to `\gdef\@subtitle{value}` where `@` is part of the name of the macro you are defining. You have a variable that holds a value, and then you define a command to ease setting up that variable. If the `@` disconcerts you, think about it like using `\setsubtitle{Value}` instead of `\setvariable\subtitlevariable{Value}`; if you want to use or retrieve the content of the variable you have to use `\subtitlevariable`. By the way, that code should have two `%` that are missing.

Comment: It's somewhat meant to hide the internals from a normal LaTeX user as well. It is perhaps easier to write `\subtitle{foo}` than `\gdef\@subtitle{foo}`, regarding the fact it needs the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair on the main document (not inside the class or package however). Please take into account the fact that `\subtitle` might be `\relaxed` later to prevent accidental change, but `\@subtitle` is still available (depends on the setup, of course)

Comment: The code is meant to do two things: 1) Make the user able to set what the subtitle should be with `\subtitle{text}`. 2) Be able to read this setting afterwards. Since `\subtitle` takes an argument, we cannot retrieve the value of it, and need a helper command. The `@`-sign is there to inhibit direct access to `\@subtitle` since `@` is of a different catcode. In the package class, `@` is set at as a normal character, so here we can retrieve the content with `\@subtitle`, and it will be replaced by whatever the user set it to.

Comment: note that the definition should be `\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}` as above, every use of`\subtitle` adds two space tokens to the input in addition to making the definition, this may or may not affect the output, depending where it is used.

Answer (score 4):

If you have

```
\newcommand\title[1]{\def\Xtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{\def\Xsubtitle{#1}}
```

then in this particular implementation, use of `\title{my thesis}` has the same effect as `\def\Xtitle{my thesis}` but it is misleading to say that `\title` is just syntactic sugar for the `\def` just as it is misleading to say that

```
\section{Introduction}
```

is syntactic sugar for several lines of spacing and font setting commands.

LaTeX can be viewed as a document markup language, allowing different implementations within TeX and increasingly in other languages such as perl or javascript.

In one class

```
\title{my thesis}
```

might simply define `\Xtitle` (or `\@title`) in another it might also trigger writing some XML citation database structure or pdf bookmark or ....

(Almost) every LaTeX command is a macro that expands to the use of lower level commands but you lose almost all the benefits of latex if you just use the low level commands and never use the macros that are defined.